# Mysql combine specific row results while respecting unselected rows

Tags: mysql

There seems to be similar questions but don't fit my particular problem. How can I accomplish this? I have made a sample table with an expected output as well.

```
 City           | population | 


Thermopolis         8
Douglas             5
Nampa               6
Eiko                4
Reno                7
Medford             3
Fresno              9
```

I want to make a group that combines Douglas, Eiko, Fresno along with their `population` column. And get the expected output:

```
Thermopolis         8
Custom_Group        18
Nampa               6
Reno                7
Medford             3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way (basically you use a `GROUP BY` and define all the groups):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(City), SUM(population)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY IF( City IN ('Douglas','Eiko','Fresno'), 1, City )
```

This groups by city, and lumps your custom group into one city. `GROUP_CONCAT` lists 'Douglas,Eiko,Fresno' as the City for that group (although you could do a similar `IF( City IN (..), 'Custom_Group', City )` if you wanted to change the group name).

Comment: Group by if seems to be the most elegant solution, thank you.

Comment: If I leave out GROUP_CONCAT it works beautifully. Except that changing the 1 to 'Custom_Group' doesn't seem to change the name of the group. It simply leaves the name of the first city in the group.

Comment: Iif you want to change the name you have to do the `IF(City IN (...), 'Custom_Group', City AS City` in the `SELECT` part - what you put in the 'GROUP BY' part is irrelevant (except that it can't be the name of a city in your table that isn't in that group, which is why I chose 1).

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware you meant on the `SELECT` part, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that hard-codes the list of cities...

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN City IN (
        'Douglas', 
        'Eiko', 
        'Fresno'
    ) THEN 'Custom_Group' ELSE City END AS City,
    SUM(Population) AS Population
FROM
    Cities
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN City IN (
        'Douglas', 
        'Eiko', 
        'Fresno'
    ) THEN 'Custom_Group' ELSE City END
```

A more sustainable solution would be to create a new table that controls your city groupings...

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(g.Group, c.City) AS City,
    SUM(c.Population) AS Population
FROM
    Cities c LEFT JOIN
    City_Groups g ON g.CityID = c.ID
GROUP BY
    IFNULL(g.Group, c.City)
```